# Changing Email sensitivity via Outlook Web Add-ins

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm trying to create an Outlook Web Add-in that will alter the sensitivity of the email itself.

Going through the documentation, I see that there is an "AlterSensitivity" method that is available on the Office.context.mailbox.item object, but I cannot figure out how to make it work.

Basically, I just want the user to click the toggle button which will change the sensitivity from confidential to normal, or normal to confidential. I know I'm not really posting any code, but I'm not sure what value that would provide.

Here is a pseudo-code mock-up:

- User Clicks button
- code checks message sensitivity
- if sensitivity is normal, change to confidential and toggle the button to be pressed
- If sensitivity is confidential, change to normal, and toggle the button to not be pressed.

Hopefully that makes sense, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API that exists today in the Web Add-in model to change the sensitivity of an item. AlterSensitivity is not an API we support. In order to change the sensitivity of an item, you would need to use EWS or REST.

Comment: Awesome, at least that points me in a better direction, thanks for the info!